# How do I amend my query to sum the top n records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query in MS Access:

```
SELECT Sum(FS) AS FS_sum, Sum(FSOF) AS FSOF_sum
FROM tbl_G_elomkv_atp AS tt
WHERE tt.ID_A = 19
```

I now want to refine this further and sum only the records for the 15 most recent based on an autonumber PK in the table: `PK_G`.

Just adding in 'Top 15' and 'order by' got me a 'domain aggregate' error so I amended the code to:

```
SELECT TOP 15 Sum(FS) AS FS_sum, Sum(FSOF) AS FSOF_sum
FROM tbl_G_elomkv_atp as tt
WHERE tt.ID_A = 19
GROUP BY tt.PK_G
ORDER BY tt.PK_G DESC
```

However, this gives a row for every one of the 15 records. How do I return a single row with the two sum values `FS_sum` and `FSOF_sum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT Sum(FS) AS FS_sum, Sum(FSOF) AS FSOF_sum
FROM (SELECT TOP 15 tt.*
      FROM tbl_G_elomkv_atp AS tt
      WHERE tt.ID_A = 19
      ORDER BY tt.PK_G DESC
     ) as tt
```

Comment: I knew it was likely to be that but couldn't figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: @Jossy . . . I know that.  They are optional in SQL Server as well, but they seem to be required by the syntax diagram (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), so I'm in the habit of always using them.